# How do I get the 'Calendar' app to display on the Dashboard?

Tags: macos, calendar, dashboard

[MacOS C-Error]

As per the title.  I've tried using `ctrl up-arrow` and dragging onto that 'desktop' but my drag is rejected...

I want to be able to see my appointments at a glance in the Dashboard, not just a static calendar with a clock.

While looking for answers to this question, I came across something called `DashCode`, which I understand does not exist for MacOS Sierra.  Can this be used to wrap the calendar app into a widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this widget, hope it can help you :)

[Download link](http://downloads.benkazez.com/iCalEvents.wdgt.zip)

Comment: Thanks!  It appears to be just a viewer.  Is it possible to add events through it?

Comment: The author, Ben Kazez, has it up as an Open-Source project on git-hub: https://github.com/bkazez/icalevents